# react setting state in a condition inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to avoid showing an alert in React Native more than once.
To do that, I am trying to update the state inside a condition which is inside a useEffect:

```
const [permissionStatus, setPermissionStatus] = useState('');
const [permissionsAlertShown, setPermissionsAlertShown] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  function handleAppStateChange() {
    if (
      AppState.currentState === 'active' &&
      permissionStatus === 'denied' &&
      !permissionsAlertShown
    ) {
      setPermissionsAlertShown(true);
      Alert.alert(
        ...
      );
    }
  }
  AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
}, [permissionStatus, permissionsAlertShown]);
```

My issue is that if I navigate away from my app and come back to it, AppState.currentState changes and since `setPermissionsAlertShown(true)` is ignored, I am shown the alert again.

How do I handle this situation?

Comment: You just need to persist the state in asyncStorage

Comment: Where does `AppState` come from?

Comment: @Maxwells.c can you please post an example?

Comment: @hackape AppState comes from React Native

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to create a callback function that will remove the listener. I will share if someone else ever looks for this.

```
const [permissionStatus, setPermissionStatus] = useState('');
const [permissionsAlertShown, setPermissionsAlertShown] = useState(false);
const handleAppStateChange = useCallback(() => {
    if (
      AppState.currentState === 'active' &&
      permissionStatus === 'denied' &&
      !permissionsAlertShown
    ) {
      setPermissionsAlertShown(true);
      Alert.alert(
        ...
      );
    }
}, [permissionStatus, permissionsAlertShown]);
useEffect(() => {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
  return () => AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
}, [handleAppStateChange]);
```

Answer (score -2):

You just need to persist the state, with [asyncStorage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage) or some other storage.

The ideal case is to use what persisted of your action (an permission enabled, an API data saved etc).

Comment: Try first learning asyncStorage. Then if you still can't figure it out, you can comment what you want